# Proper use of COUNT function in query to get percentages (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, count

This is probably answered elsewhere, but I haven't been able to properly use it due to lack of proper knowledge.

I have the following (simplified) tables:

```
users
-id
-country

group_selections
-id
-user_id
-group_id
-rank
```

I'm currently doing an INNER JOIN like so:

```
SELECT
  `group_id`, `country`
FROM `group_selections` AS `GroupSelection`
JOIN `users` AS `User`
  ON (`GroupSelection`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
GROUP BY `country`
ORDER BY `group_id`, `country`
```

Which returns rows like so:

```
| group_id |   country |
|----------|-----------|
|        1 |     Spain |
|        1 |       USA |
|        2 |    Canada |
|        2 |     Chile |
|        2 |       USA |
|        2 | Venezuela |
|        3 | Australia |
|        3 |    Canada |
|        3 |     China |
|        3 |       USA |
|        4 |     Spain |
```

What I need, essentially, is to get something like this:

```
| group_id |   country | percentage_country |
|----------|-----------|--------------------|
|        1 |     Spain |               0.50 |
|        1 |       USA |               0.50 |
|        2 |    Canada |               0.25 |
|        2 |     Chile |               0.25 |
|        2 |       USA |               0.25 |
|        2 | Venezuela |               0.25 |
|        3 | Australia |               0.25 |
|        3 |    Canada |               0.25 |
|        3 |     China |               0.25 |
|        3 |       USA |               0.25 |
|        4 |     Spain |               1.00 |
```

which is nothing more than the percentage of users from each country that choose a particular group (users can choose multiple groups to join).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c228/5)

To make it clear why: in my application, I'm trying to give an advantage to users based on their country, so if there are many users (that want to join a group) from one country compared to another, the country with fewer users gets an advantage when picking them.

This seems awfully straightforward, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution and SQLFidle is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c228/35

```
SELECT
  `GroupSelection`.`group_id`, `country`, COUNT(`country`)/`GroupCount`.member_cnt as `percentage_country`
FROM `group_selections` AS `GroupSelection`
JOIN `users` AS `User`
  ON (`GroupSelection`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
JOIN (SELECT gs.`group_id`, COUNT(*) AS `member_cnt` 
      FROM `group_selections` AS gs
      GROUP BY gs.`group_id`) `GroupCount`
  ON (`GroupSelection`.`group_id` = `GroupCount`.`group_id`)
GROUP BY `country`, `group_id`
ORDER BY `group_id`, `country`
```

Comment: I've tried this solution in the original SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc2d6/3) and it seems to work; however, when tried with a larger dataset (2500 users, 10000 selections) the percentage of countries for each group don't add up to 1. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Is it possible in your larger dataset to have a NULL country?

Comment: No, the field is set to not null and I've checked for null values anyway, with no rows returned.

Comment: I have no idea now. If you can provide some sample data, then we can debug.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly high performance, but should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  `group_id`, User.`country`, COUNT(User.`country`) / cc.cc_count  as `percentage_country`
FROM `group_selections` AS `GroupSelection`
JOIN `users` AS `User`
  ON (`GroupSelection`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
JOIN (SELECT country, count(*) as cc_count FROM users GROUP BY country) AS cc ON cc.country = User.country
GROUP BY `country`, `group_id`
ORDER BY `group_id`, `country`
```

On [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c228/17/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery in which you count the distinct countries per group and join this number back to your original query:

```
SELECT
  t.`group_id`, `country`, min(1/t.no_of_countries) as percentage
FROM `group_selections` AS `GroupSelection`
JOIN `users` AS `User`
  ON (`GroupSelection`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
INNER JOIN (SELECT `group_id`, count(distinct country) as no_of_countries
            FROM users u inner join group_selections g on u.id=g.user_id
            GROUP BY g.group_id) t ON t.group_id=GroupSelection.group_id
GROUP BY t.group_id,`country`
ORDER BY `group_id`, `country`;
```

However,your expected results do not seem to take the number of users into account within each group, only the number of countries.